# Do I have to write explicit code to ensure the backward compatibility?

Tags: android, sdk

If I specify the minimum SDK as 2.0 and the target SDK as 4.1,will I have to write explicit code to ensure backward compatibility. Like if I want to use a gesture detection feature introduced in SDK level 7 and I set the target as 7 and minimum to 3. I am asking will I need to write explicit code(which doesn't include the gesture detection features) so that it runs in targets less than 7 but greater than 3?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have to avoid calling future APIs when running on older versions of Android.  You can organize your code to select an appropriate code path at runtime, depending on the version of your OS.

[An example of how to preserve backwards-compatibility when using a new API.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to, but I don't see any logical reason to still support any API before 8 (2.2).

[image: Android Platform Distribution]

It's literally 1.6% of the market. It's not worth the effort to maintain and support such early versions any more.

That said, if you need to do version specific code, this is the way to handle it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
    //Use API 7+ code
} else {
    //Use backwards compatible code
}
```

Comment: The sdk versions I mentioned where just dummy values, I meant the versions like 2.0 and 4.1 where just examples, nothing else.
Any way thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Is there any way I can know which features are not in the target version automatically when I code?

Comment: if you use a depreceated method lint will warn you about the same.

Comment: But only in Eclipse. If you're using IntelliJ, you'll need to run Lint via command line to check against API levels (at least until Android Studio/IntelliJ 13 are released).

Comment: @kcoppock Brilliant insight indeed

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Android [official site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) on how to guarantee backwards compatibility to minimum level 4 (which is negligible up until api level 7 anyway. The slightly more significant share is usually api level 8 upwards), and always use the latest [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

Of course there are some minor code changes (such as `getSupportFragmentManager()` in replace of `getFragmentManager()`,etc). The worst you it can happen is `NoSuchMethodException` so you have to be real careful not to call API's that does not exist in lower platforms. The sdk should be very clearly advising that when it happens.